# Discuss the convergence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Discuss the convergence and the uniform convergence of the integrals for different value of $\alpha$ and $P$, where $\alpha$ and $P$ are parameters.

Hint: You may use comparison Test.

***$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\alpha x}}{\alpha+x^p}\,dx$$
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\cos\alpha x}{\alpha+x^p}\,dx$$***
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin\alpha x}{\alpha+x^p}\,dx$$

Comment: Can you tell us what you have tried? Posting a question (especially homework) without commenting on what you have tried usually does not get your question the attention it (presumably) deserves on Math.SE.

Comment: thank you i tried to solve it many times but I am not sure about the answer , this question is from my last year exam , i study for my final , for the first one its convergence for p>1 , p<1 ,α>=0 . the second and third one is convergence for all p>1 , and α>0

Comment: and i used the comparison test for the first with e^(-αx) ,

Comment: the second and third i use comparison with 1/x^p

Comment: Thanks M47145 for the edit

Comment: i need help in last two question

Answer (score 3):

**Hints:**

1. For $\alpha\geq0$, $e^{-\alpha x}\leq1$ and $\alpha+x^{p}\geq x^{p}$,
2. $|\cos y| \leq 1$ independent of $y$, and
3. $|\sin y| \leq 1$ independent of $y$.

Comment: for first one :- my answer is ( convergence for α≥0 and p>1 is that correct ?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot  , can you help me in the next two ?  Are we'll use the absolute convergence test ?

Comment: Use the absolute convergence test and then the comparison test, just like you did for the first

Comment: the answer for the second is  p>1,α>0  and the third is  α≥0 and p>1  is that correct ?

Comment: The bounds you get for the second and third should be the same

Comment: To elaborate on my previous comment, this is because $\sin$ and $\cos$ are both bounded above by the same number, and the integral is otherwise the same. Therefore, $\alpha > 0$ and $p > 1$ works for both. I don't think $\alpha = 0$ works.

Comment: How about if the denominator in the last two question (sin,cos) is (α^2+x^p) . Is it will be convergence for all value of α and p>1 ? .

Comment: No, as I said above, it will not necessarily converge if $\alpha=0$. (also you don't need to put someone's name in quotations ")

Comment: (not sure why my answer was unaccepted one month after-the-fact)